# Inverse of Pre-Image Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

I am trying to determine whether the equation $x^2-y^2+x^3+y^3=0$ defines a 1-manifold in the plane. I know that the pre-image theorem describes criteria for showing this equation does define a manifold: if all the components of the gradient are linear independent at the solutions of this equation. Clearly in this particular case the theorem does not apply, as the point $(0,0)$ is a solution and both partial derivatives are 0 at this point. My question is, does this infer that the equation does not describe a manifold, i.e. is the inverse statement of the pre-image theorem also true.
If not, what other theorems might I use to determine whether the equation describes a 1-manifold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x^2 - y^2 + x^3 + y^3 = (x+y)(x^2 - x y + y^2 + x - y)$, this is the union of the straight line $x+y=0$ and a conic (which turns out to be an ellpse).  The two intersect at $(0,0)$ and $(-2/3, 2/3)$. It's not a manifold because no neighbourhood of either of those points is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$.

[image]